# Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt after sending a file mail

Tags: c#

my file always create succesfully and After sending the file and exiting the function successfully The debug comes to MessageBox("The file was sent successfully") And.. bounces the error Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
and if i tried to delete this code from Program.cs Application.EnableVisualStyles();
my code it is doing well but the project dont have styles.
any body can fix that? or this a problem with visual studio?

```
 //build a pdf file 
 public Pdf(string name)
    {
        doc = new Document();
        ///////////////////////////////////////////

        var ARIALUNI_TFF = @"C:\Windows\Fonts\Arial.TTF";
        //Create a base font object making sure to specify IDENTITY-H
        BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(ARIALUNI_TFF, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
        
        //Create a specific font object
        myfont1 = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bf, 12);
        myfont= new iTextSharp.text.Font(bf, 16);
        ///////////
        var savepath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Directory.GetParent(Environment.CurrentDirectory).Parent.FullName, "Orders",name + ".pdf");
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(savepath, FileMode.Create));
        doc.Open();

    }
      public bool SendEmailClient(Client client)
    {
        try
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
            mail.From = new MailAddress("ryosofts7@gmail.com");
            mail.To.Add(client.Email);
            mail.Subject = "Thank you for buying from us";
            mail.Body = "Dear " + client.Name + "\n We have sent you a receipt for your purchase from us\n";

            System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
            var savepath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Directory.GetParent(Environment.CurrentDirectory).Parent.FullName, "Orders",
            client.Name + " " + client.LastName + "-" + " "+"-" +DateTime.Now.ToString("dd_MM_yyyy") + ".pdf");
            attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(savepath);
            mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
            SmtpServer.Port = 587;
            SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myEmail", "mypassword");
            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
            SmtpServer.Send(mail);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does code work on your home PC?  If you are in a Corporate Network all port 587 is forwarded to a Proxy Server and will not go to GMAIL.  Also GMAL requires the FROM address and the Credentials to be from the same account.

Comment: yes its always works but after update it dosent @jdweng

Comment: What update are your referring to?

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 
Version 16.7.4 That's what you're asking about.?

Comment: @jdweng If I remove this code Application.EnableVisualStyles(); the code Will be work and i dont have a syles after that

Comment: The code was working until you updated to VS 2019 (and Net version)?  Did you do a clean build after updating?  The intermediate object files may not of gotten updated.  Often I just delete the bin folder to force and update.  Also check the debug and release folder to see if both executables got updated.

Comment: You may of lost a template.  See following : https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sending-email-by-using-email-templates-in-asp-net-webform/

Comment: yeh the code was working before the update , and the send mail is doing well but after i receive the file and after the code finished the function and comes to MessageBox(..) its bounces the error

Comment: @jdweng i have the templates

Comment: So do you think the failure is in the template?

Comment: @jdweng No I dont think that

Comment: Doesn't make sense if you comment out the code and it works the issue is in the code that was commented out?  You can debug the template like any other code.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/debugging-a-t4-text-template?view=vs-2019

Comment: @jdweng Hey , sorry for lateing , after Lots of trying to fix i decided to change the computer i put the project on defirent computer with the lastest update and , the project works .. i think the problem with my computer and the software

Comment: Did you install all windows updates?

Answer (score -1):

In any case:  "attempt to read or write protected memory" is an indication of a *bug* in your software ... somewhere.  As others have suggested, it is probably a brand-new path that is being taken, and this path may or may not be in *your* software.  (You need to chase down the address of the instruction that triggered the failure, to see exactly where it is.)

The first "strong indication" is your statement that *"the code was working before the update."*  Can you roll-back that update to verify this?

Comment: the code was working before the update, i started with defirent computer but the computer it's slow i changed the computer and i put the project on the new computer and i dont check my code , at the first time i thouth the problem with my code becouse i changed the code , after Lots of trying to fix i decided to change the computer i put the project on defirent computer (the old computer) with the lastest update and , the project works .. i think the problem with my new computer and the software.